# About RealTerm: Serial Capture Program 2.0.0.70

Tags: uart, pic18

I have some difficulty in using RealTerm Serial System. I want to use this software as GUI to communicate with PIC18F46J50 microcontroller through UART. Firstly I want to program a echo function, but I find the empty area on the top half of GUI cannot be used to type in new words. According to the information online, I think it is allowed to type in words in this area.

Does anyone get the solution to this tiny problem? Thank you all for concerning about this question.

Sincerely
Timberjack

Comment: If I understand your question, try selecting "Half Duplex" on the "Display" tab. That oddly enough is the RealTerm equivalent to "local echo". See my answer [HERE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/106087/25328) for a similar discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Sending in Realterm can be done by clicking on the "Send" tab. Typing what you want and then send them as numbers or as ascii.

How to do this is described here:
[Serial Terminal Basics](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/real-term-windows)
under section Sending Sequences of Values.